# SharePoint task management issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePiont Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have the following requirements about task management and want to know whether SharePoint Server 2007 can implement such feature. And if cannot, what kinds of Microsoft or non-Microsoft product could achieve such goals (and could integrate with SharePoint Server 2007). I prefer Microsoft product because I have requirement to integrate task management feature into SharePoint, and I think using Microsoft product is easier for integration with SharePoint. :-)

Requirements are,

1. For task management, task dependencies can be shown, and a big task can be divided into a couple of small tasks;
2. Task assigment is based on organization hierarchy. i.e. a department manager in organization chart could assign tasks to his employees, but not employee of other department managers.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Microsoft Project Server: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Project_Server) or [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/projectserver/FX100739841033.aspx)

Comment: Any Project Server discussion forums to recommend?

Comment: I don't have any but a quick google finds some like Microsoft MSDN or at Mombu.

Comment: I am confused that I did not find any forms on MSDN. Any ideas?